# Subtracting each element of a vector from ther other in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a column vector, for example,

1

0

3

2

At each row, i want to subtract the number above it, like,

row1: null

row2: 0 - 1 = -1

row3: 3 - 0 = 3 and 3 - 1 = 2 .. etc so that to obtain something like this

null

-1

3   2

-1  2  1

Can someone guide me to an efficient MATLAB code without using a for loop, as the number of rows in my original data is too long.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something along the lines of:

```
V = [1;0;3;2];
tril(bsxfun(@minus,V,V'),-1);
```

This gives me the following:

```
ans =

 0     0     0     0
-1     0     0     0
 2     3     0     0
 1     2    -1     0
```

The main downside of this is that it will use a lot of memory if `V` is very long (but that is going to be a problem regardless, I imagine). You can potentially reduce the memory usage by making `V` sparse.